# changing aspnet user to the domain user to access iis

Tags: asp.net, wcf, security, iis, iis-5

I'm running IIS5.0 and I am trying to change the ASP.NET process account to my domain user account.

I have followed everything possible [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/192116/a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client).

When I browse the `.svc` file (this is a wcf service) I am getting this error:

> Server Application Unavailable  The
>   web application you are attempting to
>   access on this web server is currently
>   unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh"
>   button in your web browser to retry
>   your request.
>
> Administrator Note: An error message
>   detailing the cause of this specific
>   request failure can be found in the
>   application event log of the web
>   server. Please review this log entry
>   to discover what caused this error to
>   occur.

Eventlog says:

> aspnet_wp.exe could not be started.
>   The error code for the failure is
>   80070522. This error can be caused when the worker process account has
>   insufficient rights to read the .NET
>   Framework files. Please ensure that
>   the .NET Framework is correctly
>   installed and that the ACLs on the
>   installation directory allow access to
>   the configured account.

When I run the client, I get the following error:

> The content type text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 of the response message
>   does not match the content type of the
>   binding (application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom
>   encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly. The first 872
>   bytes of the response were: '

Answer (score 0):

If you put your Domain Account under IIS_WPG group, it should ideally work. If it doesn't work, there is a sure shot way of fixing it.

In IIS 6... step 1 is applicable... since you are on IIS 5, ignore step 1

1. Run it with Local System to begin with. If the applications runs, it means your IIS is configured well and you can proceed with the step 2.
2. Change the account to your domain account, and ensure that you have put the account in IIS_WPG as well. After that, run the tool called Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx
3. Browse the application now. If you still get the error, switch to the Process Monitor and stop capture [menu option].
4. Search for Access denied and fix it. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150710180311/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rahulso/archive/2006/01/18/using-filemon-regmon-to-solve-quot-access-denied-quot-issues.aspx)

Comment: tried this, it shows success for all aspnet_wp.exe process. and no access denied string. But still I get the above mentioned error "Server Application Unavailable"

Comment: Did you check your event logs? Server application unavailable error will typically cause an event entry be written.

Answer (score 0):

From ASP.NET 2.0 onwards, the correct method to ensure that a user account has the correct rights to run as the worker process identity is to run this command:

```
aspnet_regiis -ga [account]
```

You need to run the aspnet_regiis command that matches the ASP.NET version you plan on running:

**ASP.NET 2.0 -**

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga [account]
```

**ASP.NET 4.0 -**

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga [account]
```